# How to obtain a pointer to pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm supposed to write a function to remove the first node in a linked list.
List is defined like so:

```
struct ListNode{
    int nInfo;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *createNode(int nInfo) {
    ListNode *node;
    node->nInfo = nInfo;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void insertNode(struct ListNode **list, struct ListNode *node) {
    //Sorting list after nInfo
    struct ListNode *temp;
    struct ListNode *tmpList = *list;
    if(*list != NULL) { //List exists
        while((tmpList->next != NULL)) {
            if((tmpList->nInfo >= node->nInfo) && (tmpList->next->nInfo < node->nInfo)) {
                break;
            }
            tmpList = tmpList->next;
        }
        //Found where to insert the node
        temp = tmpList->next;   //Saving old nextnode
        tmpList->next = node;   //Assigning new nextnode
        node->next = temp;  //Re-inserting old node
    }
    else{
        *list = node;
    }
}
```

The function for removing the first node looks like this:

```
void deleteFirst(struct ListNode **list) {
    //Delete first node
    struct ListNode *temppointer = *list;
    if(temppointer == NULL)
        return; //List is NULL
    *list = temppointer->next;
}
```

I use the functions like so:

```
struct ListNode *list = createNode(100);
struct ListNode *node1 = createNode(50);
insertNode(list, node1); //Gives error, cannot convert ListNode* to ListNode**
deleteFirst(list); //Same error
```

I can't figure out how to obtain a pointer to the list pointer.

Comment: How do you allocate your nodes? Better also show is the function to insert nodes, and an example of how you call insert and delete.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Editet the question to include the updated code and an example of how I call the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we suspected, you forget to allocate memory for your nodes:

```
struct ListNode *createNode(int nInfo) {
    ListNode *node;
    node->nInfo = nInfo;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Your `*node` is a pointer, but it still points to nothing. You must ask the heap for memory for your node:

```
    ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

Then in DeleteNode, you must return the memory to the heap, as you no longer need it:

```
void deleteFirst(struct ListNode **list) {
    //Delete first node
    struct ListNode *temppointer = *list;
    if(temppointer == NULL)
        return; //List is NULL
    *list = temppointer->next;
    free(temppointer);    // release the memory.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention! The function you wrote for creating a node cannot work as it is: the node is allocated on the stack, in the context of the function, and it is invalid after the function has exited.

You have to allocate the memory for the node on the heap,  using (p.e.) malloc. The function that remove the node from the list is responsable for its deallocation, usually using free.

Comment: ummm...why? You mean to say, I cannot return a `struct` from a function?

Comment: you are wrong about stack. but the warning stay still.

Comment: Simonel, I made this mistake too some time ago: he returns the complete node, not  a pointer, and if he assigns it upon return, the compiler copies the complete node. Only now will the stack be reused.

Comment: ok. now createNode() is completely wrong. you didn't allocate memory to  new node

Answer (score 0):

[posting as an answer to get the formatting right]
Note: your insert() function is overly complex. It can be reduced to

```
void insertNode(struct ListNode **list, struct ListNode *node) {
    for( ; *list ; list = &(*list)->next ) { //List exists
        if(*(list)->nInfo >= node->nInfo) break;
        }
    //Found where to insert the node
    node->next = *list;
    *list = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode{
    int nInfo;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *createNode(int nInfo) {
    struct ListNode *node=malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if(node){
        node->nInfo = nInfo;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void insertNode(struct ListNode **list, struct ListNode *node) {

    // for safety
    if(!list) return;
    if(!node) return;


    //Sorting list after nInfo

    struct ListNode *temp;
    struct ListNode *tmpList = *list;

    if(tmpList!= NULL) { //List exists
        while(tmpList->next) {

            if( 
                ((tmpList->nInfo)>= (node->nInfo))  
                && 
                ((tmpList->next->nInfo) < (node->nInfo))
              ) {
                break;
            }
            tmpList = tmpList->next;
        }
        //Found where to insert the node
        temp = tmpList->next;   //Saving old nextnode
        tmpList->next = node;   //Assigning new nextnode
        node->next = temp;  //Re-inserting old node
    }
    else{
        *list = node;
    }
}


void deleteFirst(struct ListNode **plist) {
    if(!plist) return;

    struct ListNode *list=*plist;
    if(!list) return;

    *plist=list->next;
    free(list);
    return ;

}


void printNodes(char *title,struct  ListNode *list){
    printf("\n== %s\n",title);
    while(list){
        printf("\t%d\n",list->nInfo);
        list=list->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    struct ListNode *list = createNode(100);
    struct ListNode *node1 = createNode(50);
    insertNode(&list, node1); 
    printNodes("on start",list);

    insertNode(&list, createNode(70));
    printNodes("after add 70",list);

    deleteFirst(&list); 
    printNodes("after del first",list);

}
```